# Flag fields from table 1 that also bellowings to table 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I have two table (table1 and table2) where table2 is a subset of table1, what I am trying to do is a select statement that return a boolean if a field of tabl1 is also in the table2

For example:
 Table 1 has item1, item2, item3 and item4
 Table 2 has item2 and item4

I am trying to create a select statement that returns

item1, false
item2, true
item3, false
item4, true

So far I was able to select all the elements that is in table1 but not in table2 or all elements that isn't in table1 but is on table2. However I cannot find the solution for this problem and I can't get the correct words to google it. I hope someone can help me.

I am running the queries in PHP the database I am using is mySQL

Comment: is `item1, false item2, true item3, false item4, true` really the desired output? can you give some sample table data and the actual output you are looking for?

Comment: @Sean yes that was the desired output, basically I have a table of products and another one with products available at the moment, I want a query where I could see all my products and all that are available at the same time! I think I got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can left join `table2` and if the item isn't in `table2` then it will be null:

```
SELECT
  table1.item,
  CASE WHEN table2.item IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS ItemIsInTable2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.item = table2.item
```